# Unable to run. map on array in JavaScript / React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am getting an error whilst mapping through the nested array `locations`. Previously this logic has worked and I think the array type is the same so not sure why this is not working on this `locations` array.

Error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.state.locations.map is not a function
```

Mapping code

```
<tbody>
  {this.state.locations.map(location =>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <Link to={`${this.state.tracker.key}/locations/`}>{location.name}</Link>
    </td>
    <td>{location.canal}</td>
    <td>{location.closesttown}</td>
    <td>{location.comment}</td>
  </tr>
  )}
</tbody>
```

This is the array that is not iterating.

```
0: {key: "79", doc: e, name: "", canal: "", closesttown: "", comment: ""}
1: {key: "Nq", doc: e, name: "", canal: """", closesttown: "",comment: ""}
```

This is the array that I can map through with no error

```
0: {key: "Fr", doc: e, title: "Location", description: "My fav locations", author: "Gemma"}
1: {key: "G6", doc: e, title: "Gas", description: "Date of starting new gas cannister", author: "Gemma"}
2: {key: "za", doc: e, title: "", description: "", author: ""}
```

**this is where locations is initially created:**

```
this.state = {
      tracker: {},
      key: '',
      locations: {},
    };
```

**This is where I get the data for locations:**

```
onCollectionUpdate = (querySnapshot) => {
    const locations = [];
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      const { name, canal, closesttown ,comment } = doc.data();
      locations.push({
        key: doc.id,
        doc, // DocumentSnapshot
        name,
        canal,
        closesttown,
        comment,
      });
    });
    this.setState({
      locations
   });
  }
```

Comment: What's the initial value of `locations`? Is it an array? How are you setting data in `locations`?

Comment: @AjeetShah I have updated with these details (array)

Comment: Initial value of locations should be empty array, so do `this.state = {
      tracker: {},
      key: '',
      locations: [],
    };`

Comment: Oh wow I completely missed that!!! Thank you so much!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You have locations in your state as an object. If you are going to run .map on it it needs to be an array.

locations: [],

2. It looks like the .map function is trying to run before there is a value in this.state.locations . So it is trying to run .map on something that is not an array/undefined/null.

Add a ? before the .map, this way it will not run the .map until locations is defined and not null.

```
  {this.state.locations?.map(location =>
```

See this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) for more information on ?. notation.

3. You might also want to look at the second item in the locations array. The canal property has two sets of quotations. It should only be "" not """".

Comment: Thank you! Problem solved. Yes I have updated the "" and have now updated locations to be an array. 
That's a really useful tip on the '?'. I will use that.

Answer (score 0):

The second object of the first array is not valid.
Try to change the "canal" value of the second object from:

```
""""
```

to

```
""
```

Comment: Thanks for noticing. I have updated this but is not the issue with the iteration.